# Microsoft office 2007

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have list of 5000 mobile numbers starting with 5 I want to add a zero in the beginning. I tried using find and replace but it zero at starting of every 5. Please help me to solve this problem. I tried wild card * but no help

Comment: 1) Word is not the place to do this kind of thing. 2) Assuming the data is formatted in some intelligible fashion, copy it to Excel, then concatenate. 3) FYI, the question shows no attempt to research the answer yourself, or even to be specific enough. This is not the right site to ask it.

Comment: Macro (VBA) program may help. But it depends how the mobile numbers exist in word file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not making two columns in excel. One column with 0's, the other with your phone numbers. Then on the third column use a formula to add both columns. =A2&B2 <-- just as an example.